# SQL Temp table Array to perfrom rolling caluclations

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, temp-tables, self-join

I wish to use some sort of SQL array to subtract values from a certain row (`QTYOnHand`) that decreases that row value every time and throws it into a rolling calculation for the other rows. I've been thinking of some sort of Self Join/Temp Table solution, but not sure how to formulate. Also, All the results will be partitioned by the `ItemID` below. Help would be appreciated.

Here's some data, If I do a simple row by row subtraction I will get this: 17-3 = 14, 17-5 = 12 and so on.

(Item_ID)  (ItemQty) (QTYOnHand)  (QtyOnHand - ItemQty)

```
123         3        17              14 
123         5        17              12
123         4        17              13
456         7        12              5
456         8        12              4
456         2        12              10
456         3        12              9
789         2        6               4
789         2        6               4
789         2        6               4
```

These are the results that I want, where I subtract every next value from the new QTYOnHand-ItemQty column value. Looks like 17-3 then 14 -5 then 9 -4 for Item_ID (123):

(Item_ID)  (ItemQty)  (QTYOnHand)   (QtyOnHand - ItemQty)

```
123         3        17              14 
123         5        17              9
123         4        17              5
456         7        12              5
456         8        12              -3
456         2        12              -5
456         3        12              -8
789         2        6               4
789         2        6               2
789         2        6               0
```

Comment: `sum() over (order by)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
;with cte as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Item_ID order by Item_ID) rn
    from YourTable
)
, cte2 as
(
    select Item_ID, ItemQty, QTYOnHand, Case when rn = 1 then QTYOnHand else 0 end - ItemQty as calc, rn
    from cte
)
select Item_ID, ItemQty, QTYOnHand, sum(calc) over (partition by Item_ID order by rn) as [QtyOnHand - ItemQty]
from cte2 t1
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bf4479b405ebacfadb657d5606c6038)**.

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. I just took out the CTEs and switched them with temp tables. Pretty simple to be honest

Comment: @AlexMusser It's never easy until it's done :) You can accept the answer so that others can know that the questions is answered correctly and the answer was useful.